# copy/move files on remote server linux

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, ksh, scp

I log into `server_a` and run `.sh` file, which has the following script:

```
scp user@server_b:/my_folder/my_file.xml user@server_b:/my_new_folder/
```

to copy files from `my_folder` to `my_new_folder` at `server_b`.  It doesn't throw an error, but no files are copied.

Notes:

- `server_b` is accessed by the pre-set rsa_keys.
- `server_a`: unix
- `server_b`: ubuntu
- can SCP files from/to these servers without any issues

The end goal is to move or copy/remove files.

Comment: As long as you have `ssh` access to all 3, you can `scp` or `rsync` to all 3. You cannot pass-through `a->b->c` in a single command without port-forwarding `c on b`. Other than that, it is really no difference from a local copy. If you haven't used `rsync` it is by far the swiss-army-knife of remove (and local) file transfers. Worth learning as it is usually installed by default on most (if not all) distros.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two possibilities:

1. Connect from `server_a` to `server_b` and do local copy:

   ```
   ssh user@server_b "cp /my_folder/my_file.xml /my_new_folder/"
   ```
2. Do copy over the `server_a`. Your method would require the `server_b` to be able to authenticate to itself, which is probably not the case:

   ```
   scp -3 user@server_b:/my_folder/my_file.xml user@server_b:/my_new_folder/
   ```

Also note that your code copies only one file and not files as you write in the title.

Comment: Jakuje, The first option worked for multiple files.  'ssh user@server_b "cp /my_folder/*.xml /my_new_folder/"'

Answer (score 0):

If you are logged on to the server, why are you authenticating again:

```
scp user@server_b:/my_folder/my_file.xml user@server_b:/my_new_folder/
```

You should be in the directory of file or simply use scp and use `-v` parameter to see the debug information.

Run as follows:

```
scp -v /my_folder/my_file.xml user@server_b:/my_new_folder/
```

It is not a directory nor it is recursive, so you do not need to `-r` parameter.